# ActiveRecord: match fields that start with plus (+)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to get all records where my phone field starts with a '+'

```
Company.where("phone LIKE ?", "+%")       // RETURNS 0 RESULTS
```

and for some reason its listing zero results, even when there are results that start with '+'

I also tried to use a `\` in order to escape the special meaning of '+' to no avail.

Although, if I try to match string that start with `+1` for example, it works as expected.

```
Company.where("phone LIKE ?", "+1%")      // WORKS FINE
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL query that get generated when you run `Company.where("phone LIKE ?", "+%")`? BTW which DB you are using?

Comment: `postgres` DB. The query that works: `SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE (phone LIKE '+1%')`  The query that does not work: `SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE (phone LIKE '+%')`

Comment: Both are working for me..try regex `Company.where("phone ~* ?", '\A[+]')`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I tried `NOT` when `where` didn't work, but both didn't work as expected. Updated my comment with the `WHERE` query

Comment: regexp doesn't work either?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon your regex works. Thanks! Any clue how to make the LIKE query work for `+`?

Comment: Not sure what's up with you, it works for me here well..all give same results, what's the datatype of that column?

Comment: Its string type. I am running postgres 9.6.3

Comment: Rails string type, which I believe is `varchar` in postgres.

Comment: strange..it should work then..I copy-pasted your where clause exactly from the post. Nevermind, you have the working solution now..

Comment: Ok, for the record, I am running the following: Ruby 2.2.4; Rails 5.0.2; Activerecord 5.0.2; pg 0.20.0

Comment: Its the quotation marks, using single quotes to enclose the regex did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Its the quotation marks!

```
Company.where("phone LIKE ?", '+%')
```

Using `'` single quotes instead of `"` double-quotes, fixed the query.